# Can I use AgensGraph just to migrate data?

Tags: migration, agens-graph

AgensGraph is installed and used on my other servers. 
Well, I am using PostgreSQL on one server. 
I would like to change that server to AgensGraph, which has a lot of data stored there. 
So can I do data migration to AgensGraph like using pg_dump? 
Or is there another way for task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use pg_dump and also you can use FDW extension to migrate your data into AgensGraph .  [Example](https://bitnine.net/tutorial/english-tutorial.html)